# If $L$ is linear function, when does $\lim \limits_{|h| \to 0} (|L(h)|/|h|)$ exist?

Tags: limits, linear-transformations

Assume that $L$ is a linear function (maybe for simplicity $L : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ but if possible I would like to have no restrictions on Banach spaces).

Under what conditions (and what is the proof, if any) is it the case that the following limit exists.

$$ \lim \limits_{|h| \to 0} \frac{|L(h)|}{|h|} $$

Answer (score 2):

Since $L$ is linear, we have to have
$$
\lvert L(h)\rvert=\lvert h\rvert\cdot\left\lvert L\left(\frac{h}{\lvert h\rvert}\right)\right\rvert
$$
so the existence of the limit $\displaystyle\lim_{\lvert h\rvert\to 0}\frac{\lvert L(h)\rvert}{\lvert h\rvert}$ means $\lvert L\rvert$ is constant on the sphere $\{x\in\operatorname{dom}L:\lvert x\rvert =1\}$.  In other words, a nontrivial $L$ is an isometric embedding followed by a scaling.

Comment: Thanks! Do you by any chance know more of equivalent statements or any reference text where such are discussed?